# How to get options_for_select to honor &nbsp; tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm trying to indent options in a select list of categories based upon their hierarchical level, e.g. `Category`,  `Subcategory`,   `Subsubcategory`.

I've tried:
`<% options = options_for_select @categories.map{|c| [("&nbsp;" * c.level) + c.name, c.id]} %>`,
but this renders as `&nsbp;Subcategory` and `&nbsp;&nbsp;Subsubcategory`.

I've tried:
`<% options = options_for_select @categories.map{|c| [(" " * c.level) + c.name, c.id]} %>`,
but this ignores the spaces and renders as `Subcategory` and `Subsubcategory`.

As a test, I tried `<%= ("&nbsp;" * 3) + "hello" %>`, and this renders how I'd expect it to:    `hello`.

Does anyone know how to get the results I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `(("&nbsp;" * c.level) + c.name).html_safe`. The problem is in the `options_for_select` helper method using `html_escape`, which escapes your `&nbsp;` entities. Adding the `html_safe` will allow the `html_escape` method called from the `options_for_select` helper to avoid escaping the spaces.

Comment: ```html_safe``` marks a whole string as safe, so before doing it it highly recommended to make sure that ```c.level``` and ```c.name``` cannot contain any user-input. Otherwise it make sense to escape them using ```h()``` helper.